# Delete cell from old range and calculation then based on new range VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA and haven't really tried much so I'm hoping this is a relatively simple problem and somebody will be able to help.

What I want is a function with a defined range, then if a cell value is =0, this cell to be deleted from the range. Once all zeros are deleted, to run a simple "If" calculation to give my result.

What I have so far is as follows...

```
Function BestCalc(rng As Range, weighted As Double)

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = 0 Then
        newrng = rng - ActiveCell.rng
    End If
Next
' Gets rid of zeros in range

m = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(newrng) ' Mean of newrng
s = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(newrng) ' St dev of newrng
n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(0.9999, m, s) ' Inverse of normal approx
v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Var(newrng) ' Variance of newrng
c = Abs((v - m)) ' Absolute value of (variance - mean)

If c <= 20 Then
    BestCalc = n
' Normal distribution

Else
    BestCalc = weighted
' Returns weighted average on sheet

End If

End Function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. The way you were trying to delete the cell within the range cannot be done through VBA.

I adjusted your code and built the string of the range, then passed that into a Range object.

```
Function BestCalc(rng As Range, weighted As Double)

Dim cell As Range
Dim newrng As String

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        newrng = newrng & "," & cell.Address
    End If
Next
' Gets rid of zeros in range

newrng = Mid(newrng, 2, Len(newrng) - 1)


m = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(newrng)) ' Mean of newrng
s = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range(newrng)) ' St dev of newrng
n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(0.9999, m, s) ' Inverse of normal approx
v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Var(Range(newrng)) ' Variance of newrng
c = Abs((v - m)) ' Absolute value of (variance - mean)

If c <= 20 Then
    BestCalc = n
' Normal distribution

Else
    BestCalc = weighted
' Returns weighted average on sheet

End If

End Function
```

Comment: This works, thanks very much! I think I can follow the first par however, why do you take the mid point of the range? Sorry if this is me being stupid!

Comment: When the string `newrng` is built the very first one will not have a value in the statement `newrng = newrng & "," & cell.Address`, so the statement `newrng = Mid(newrng,2, Len(newrng) -1)` removes the preceding `,`

Comment: FYI if you want all the rest of the string you don't need to specify the length: `newrng = Mid(newrng,2)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you just create an array of the non-zero values:

```
Function BestCalc(rng As Range, weighted As Double)

    Dim cell                  As Range
    Dim vNew()
    Dim lCounter
    Dim m                     As Double
    Dim s                     As Double
    Dim n                     As Double
    Dim v                     As Double
    Dim c                     As Double


    ReDim vNew(1 To rng.Count)

    lCounter = 1

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value2 <> 0 Then
            vNew(lCounter) = cell.Value2
            lCounter = lCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve vNew(1 To lCounter - 1)
    ' Gets rid of zeros in range

    m = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(vNew)    ' Mean of newrng
    s = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(vNew)    ' St dev of newrng
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(0.9999, m, s)    ' Inverse of normal approx
    v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Var(vNew)    ' Variance of newrng
    c = Abs((v - m))    ' Absolute value of (variance - mean)

    If c <= 20 Then
        BestCalc = n
        ' Normal distribution

    Else
        BestCalc = weighted
        ' Returns weighted average on sheet

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: This seems to work so thanks a lot! However, I have no experience or understanding of arrays at the moment so don't really understand why it works haha!